# How repair error for node-config in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript2.0, node-config

After installing node-config and @types/config:

```
npm install config
npm install @types/config
```

When I am trying to use in my app:

```
import config from 'config';
```

I am getting the error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'
```

I installed the `'fs'` module but still got this error.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you trying to access 'fs'?

Comment: So, I'm just trying to use module config in my ts file
like this
import * as cfg from " config"

export interface configuration {
    appId: string,
    src: string,
    version string;
}

export const facebook Config: Config = cfg.get < Config > ("cfg");

and got this error
but if you open config.The JS file I see this code:
// Dependences
var Yaml = null,    // External libraries are lazy-loaded
    VisionmediaYaml = null,  // only if these file types exist.
...
    FileSystem = require('fs');

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to use `node-config` in frontend code or React Native, where the `fs` module is not available. This is [not supported])https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/issues/367).

There should be no need to install the `fs` module when using `node-config` with Node.js-- the `fs` module is built into Node.js.